# How do I alter this code to Instead code a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I alter this code to Instead code a javascript function that is called from an onload event handler of the body tag.  The function should use the methods of the dom for creating new "option" elements, properly configuring, and appending to the select element?

```
<select id="listname" onchange="showEmployee(this.value)">
<option value="choose" selected>choose employee</option>
```

Comment: <select id="listname" onchange="showEmployee(this.value)">
     <option value="choose" selected>choose employee</option>

Comment: Is it ok to use jQuery? or do you want Javascript only?

Answer (score 1):

> code a javascript function that is called from an onload event handler of the body tag

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    // code here
}
</script>
```

> The function should use the methods of the dom for creating new "option" elements, properly configuring, and appending to the select element

```
var opt = new Option("option text", "val");
document.getElementById("listname").appendChild(opt);
// or in html5: document.getElementById("listname").add(opt);
```

Now all you have to do is put both together.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addOption(selectTagId) {
    var select = document.getElementById(selectTagId);

    var option = document.createElement("option");        
    option.value = "choose";
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("choose employee"));

    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: ^Set addOption as the body's onload event handler.